# При нажатии на картинку должен раскрываться список, почему не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

Не понимаю в чем проблема. Картинка является кнопкой, при нажатии должен выпадать список, но ничего не происходит

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("others").classList.toggle("show");
}
    
// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 good-block dropdown">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><img src="/content/images/product-icons/others.png" alt="Прочее" style="width:261px"></button>
  <div class="good-image newElem dropdown-content" id="others">
      <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
      <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
      <a href="#">Ещё один пункт</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: потому что нажатие на кнопку это такое же нажатие на окно браузера. То есть срабатывают два скрипта сразу. И на открытие и на закрытие. Читайте что такое всплытие событий https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling#prekraschenie-vsplytiya для решения вашей задачи надо в функцию myFunction передать event (myFunction(event)) и далее вызвать event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: violet;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: blue;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: beige}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Кнопка</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">&#128270;</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
    <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
    <a href="#">Еще один пункт меню</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код и не будет работать. В похожей теме дан ответ на ваш вопрос:
[onclick tag button doesn't work in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507661/onclick-tag-button-doesnt-work-in-angular)
в комментарии от **student dev**

**Отвыкайте привязывать события непосредственно в самом элементе**.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    
    button = document.querySelector(".dropbtn").addEventListener("click", _dropmenu);    

    function _dropmenu(){
        dropDown = document.querySelector("#others");
        dropDown.classList.toggle("show");   
    }

    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
        }
    }    
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Кнопка</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="functions.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-3 good-block dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="dropbtn">&#128270;
           <!--<img src="/content/images/product-icons/others.png" alt="Прочее" style="width:261px">-->
        </button>
        <div class="good-image newElem dropdown-content" id="others">
            <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
            <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
            <a href="#">Ещё один пункт</a>
        </div>
      </div>   
</body>
</html>
```